# what is the use of total(currentMeausure within head set) in cognos

Tags: database, function, cognos, cognos-11

I have a question regarding COGNOS inbuilt function.

I have a report of another developer in which he is using the inbuilt function **total(currentMeausure within head set)** in COGNOS. My task is to enhance the report. And the fields which have to be enhanced are using this function and I have no idea what this function is doing here.

Thanks,
Regards
Hajrah Naeem

I have searched a lot on google but didn't find accurate description about it. Can anyone explain me this function in easy way with some example so that I can continue my work?

Comment: You got an answer to your question, but never gave any feedback, nor marked it as accepted. Any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Total is the aggregation to be done on the measure.

CurrentMeasure is either the defaultMeasure on the  Crosstab or the Measure projected on an edge

Within set(head(dimension/level/set,N)) means the first N members of the defined object.

So for total(currentMeasure within set(head([ProductLine],3)) would give you total of the first 3 members in the ProductLine level.